# Predicate Logic Natural Deduction: $∃x P(x) ⊢P(x)$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I am really puzzled right now.

To solve the issue, I need to prove this formular:

$$ \exists x P(x) \vdash P(x) $$

with the [natural deduction rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3056842/predicate-logic-natural-deduction-%e2%88%83x-px-%e2%8a%a2px#comment6302453_3056842) for propositional and predicate logic.

I am sure this example should not be that difficult but, yep, now I am here.

For me, it should not be a counter example, so it should be solvable. I started to use exists elimination to get rid of the $\exists$, but than I end up with something like this:

\begin{align} \exists x P(x) \vdash P(x) \\
1.&\ \exists x P(x)  \ \text{(prem)} \\
2.&\ P(x_0) \ \text{($x_0$ fresh/free)} \\
3.&\  \dots (get \ x \ instead \ of \ x_0)\\
4.&\ P(x)
\end{align}

So I miss the little hint how I can transform the new variable to the existing one.

I hope someone can guide me.

Thank you.

Comment: How are your rules defined? There are many systems of natural deduction, each with their own rules.  And, given that $\vdash$ means: 'can be derived using the rules of the system we're working with', we'd need to know those rules before we can help you.

Comment: This _should_ not be possible to derive. If, for example, we're working in $\mathbb N$ and $P(x)$ is $x=0$, then $\exists x(x=0)$ is true, but $x=0$ is not in general true -- and you shouldn't be able to derive anything but truths when you start with truths.

Comment: Rules: https://teaching.iaik.tugraz.at/_media/lub/deduction.pdf

Comment: @whati001 As Henning says, the statement you're trying to prove is false.

Comment: It might be a good idea to backtrack to the problem you were trying to solve *before* setting your heart on proving the false claim presented above.

Comment: Thanks for posting a link for the rules ... one more question: some of the rules involving quantifiers involve terms $t$ ... how are they defined in your system?

Comment: @Bram28 _t_ just an arbitrary variable with substitute variable _x_. But as Henning and Alex mentioned, the statement is false

Comment: @whati001 I agree that semantically the statement doesn't intuitively make much sense given as $P(x)$ has a free variable $x$ that $\exists x \ P(x)$ does not have. However, the $\vdash$ is about *syntactic* derivability: that is, is there a formal derivation that allows you to end up with $P(x)$ starting with $\exists x \ P(s)$. For example, the system you are working with could have just defined a formal inference rule *exactly* to this effect (this is why I was asking what exactly your inference rules are). Again, I don't why one would, as semantically it doesn't make any sense, but still

Comment: @whati001 In fact, if you are telling me that $t$ can be any *variable*, then there is a chance it indeed could become derivable, as for $t$ we could simply use $x$, since $x$ is a *variable* as well ... Of course, it's not a 'fresh' variable, as the rules indicate, but what this means is that one would have to do a bit of work to show that $P(x)$ is in fact not derivable from $\exists x \ P(x)$. I was hoping that $t$ had to be a term that is variable-free, for then that proof would become a lot easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by Henning Makholm's comment, $\exists x P(x) \vdash P(x)$ is not provable. If it were provable then you could take a derivation of $\exists x P(x) \vdash P(x)$ and, by applying the rule $\forall_I$ in [your list](https://teaching.iaik.tugraz.at/_media/lub/deduction.pdf) for natural deduction, you would get a derivation of $\exists x P(x) \vdash \forall x P(x)$, which is not provable. Indeed, $\exists x P(x) \vdash \forall x P(x)$ means that if there exists something with the property $P$ then everything has the property $P$, which is clearly falsifiable: take $\mathbb{N}$ as domain, and let $P(x)$ be the property "$x$ is even", so that in this structure $\exists x P(x)$ is true but $\forall x P(x)$ is false.

Said differently, there is no way to fill the dots in your attempt of derivation, using natural deduction inference rules.